# cmd.exeで起動ディレクトリを相対パスで指定したい

Tags: windows, cmd

cmd.exeへのショートカットを作成して起動したときに現在のディレクトリより下にあるabcディレクトリに移動したいとします。
このとき[cmd.exeへのショートカットのプロパティ]→[ショートカットタブ]→[作業フォルダー]に相対パスを指定したのですがいろいろ試してみてもディレクトリ移動してくれません。

絶対パスで指定した場合は問題なくディレクトリ移動します。
相対パス指定はどのようにすれば良いでしょうか。
(.batを使えば解決するのですが、ショートカットだけでのやり方があるのか知りたいです)
windows8.1です。

Comment: なぜショートカットを作成したいのでしょうか？ [XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2701/xy-%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%E4%BD%95%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B)になっている可能性があります。

Comment: `Windows ショートカット 作業フォルダ 相対パス`で検索するとこんな記事が出てきます。何か参考になれば。[トリックショートカットの作成](https://qiita.com/jtFuruhata/items/58b5631ec27038aa1312), [ショートカットを相対パスで指定する方法　\[コンピューター\]](https://yogi.blog.ss-blog.jp/2018-07-20), [相対パスの指定方法](http://dulunoj.com/2018/02/13/%E7%9B%B8%E5%AF%BE%E3%83%91%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AE%E6%8C%87%E5%AE%9A%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95/), [ショートカットで指定するパスを相対パスで指定する方法](https://www.projectgroup.info/tips/Windows/comm_0058.html), [Using relative paths for Windows shortcuts](https://superuser.com/q/644407)

Comment: 取り急ぎ、なぜショートカットを作成したいかについてですが、cmd.exeの起動とディレクトリ移動をダブルクリック一発で行うためです。cmd.exeショートカットの置いてある場所と作業したい場所は違うのですが、起動後に毎回コマンドプロンプトからディレクトリ移動するのは手間なので。

Comment: あとフルパスじゃなく相対指定したいのは、作業フォルダを移動しても変わらず動作させるためです。実際フォルダを整理してたら動かなくなってしまって書き換えるのは大変です。

Comment: 単純にはこれらで良いのでは？[Windows10で『コマンドウィンドウをここで開く』を復活する](https://qiita.com/leon-joel/items/5fd4758b7031f3844c0a), [［Shift］＋右クリックメニューに「コマンドウィンドウをここで開く」を復活させる方法](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1709/15/news025.html), [Windows10／Shift＋右クリックで「コマンドウィンドウをここで開く」を復活させる](https://www.imuza.com/entry/2018/01/10/151452) Windows8だとこちら [Shiftキーを押さないで「コマンド ウィンドウをここで開く」メニューを表示する](http://suyamasoft.blue.coocan.jp/Windows/Windows8/CmdExtended/index.html), [Windows8でコマンドプロンプトをエクスプローラーから開く](https://www.relief.jp/docs/018212.html)

Comment: 先に少しだけ、知りたいのはcmd.exeのへのショートカットの「作業フォルダー」という入力場所の指定方法です。「リンク先」ではないです。cmd.exeでショートカットを作ったらそれはどこでも起動できますが、やりたいのはその後自動的に移動させたいのです。その指定が「作業フォルダー」でここには絶対パスなら問題なく自動移動してくれます。ここを相対パスで指定する方法が知りたいのです。

Comment: 教えていただいたリンク先を全て拝見しましたが、全て「リンク先」を指定するものか、やりたいことと違う内容のようです。でも参考になりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 「リンク先」指定方法でも一応試しましたが移動はしませんでした。

Comment: カレントディレクトリが `./abc` の状態でコマンドプロンプトが開いてほしいだけであれば、 `abc` ディレクトリが存在する場所に `cd ./abc` と `cmd /k` の2行を書いた `open_cmd.bat` のようなファイルを作成しておいて、これをダブルクリックして起動すればよいのではないでしょうか？

Comment: ```cd ./abc```と```cmd /k```で.batにする方法もダブルクリック一度だけで済むので便利ですね。ありがとうございます。

Comment: あと気が付かなかったのですが教えて頂いたページでexplorerで開くディレクトリを相対パスで指定できる方法があってそれも勉強になりました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問からは、以下2点をどのように考えているか？ が明確では無いですね。

- **現在のディレクトリ** とは何を指すのか？ それはどうやって決まるのか？
- 作成した **cmd.exeへのショートカットを起動する** という方法や手順は何か？

---

そこで上記2点を以下のように仮定してみました。

- **現在のディレクトリ** とは **cmd.exeへのショートカットが存在するディレクトリ** のこと
- **cmd.exeへのショートカットを起動する** とは **そのショートカットをダブルクリックする** または **そのショートカットを選択してからEnterキーを押下する** こと

---

その上で、ショートカットのプロパティを以下のように設定すれば、コマンドプロンプトを起動したときに(少なくともWindows10ならば)目的のフォルダに移動できます。

- 「作業フォルダー(S):」の欄は空欄とするか、ショートカットが存在しているディレクトリに合わせる
- 「リンク先(T):」の内容を以下に設定する

  ```
  C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /K CD 移動先指定(相対パスが指定可能)
  ```
- 「詳細設定(D)...」の「管理者として実行(R)」はチェックしない

これは、CMD.EXEのHELPで出てくる以下のオプションを適用したものです。

> /K      "文字列" に指定されたコマンドを実行しますが、終了しません。

ショートカットのあるディレクトリの下の **abc** ディレクトリに移動したいならば「リンク先(T):」の欄を以下のように設定します。

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /K CD abc
```

移動した先で更に何かを行いたい場合は、その後ろに`&`で接続してコマンドを続けます。バッチファイルを指定することも出来ます。

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /K CD abc & ECHO ディレクトリ移動テスト
```

とか、

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /K CD abc & SAMPLE.BAT
```

といったやり方です。

---

ちなみに **「作業フォルダー(S):」の欄が空欄** の時に **cmd.exeへのショートカットを起動する** 方法が、**ショートカットがカレントディレクトリに無い場合にコマンドプロンプトからショートカットのフルパス(Xxxx.lnk)を指定して実行する** だと出来ませんでした。

**ショートカットがカレントディレクトリに有る場合ならばコマンドプロンプトからショートカットのフルパスでもファイル名だけでも指定して実行する** だと「作業フォルダー(S):」の欄が空欄でも出来ました。

Comment: >2点
まさにおっしゃる通りです。

>リンク先で指定
こんなやり方があるんですね。
ありがとうございます。
同じですがこれでもうまくいきました。

%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /K cd abc

Answer (score 1):

直接の回答ではありませんが、現在のディレクトリより下にあるabcディレクトリをダブルクリックで開き、
そのフォルダーのパスが表示されている場所でcmdと入力し、エンターを押すとそのフォルダーがコマンドプロンプトで開きます。これ以外と便利ですよ。

Comment: こんなことできるなんて意外過ぎて驚きました！